# What is the eqvivalent to Jquery focusout() in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am rewriting a jquery function and I would like to know how to write the jquery focusout function in vanilla?

```js
var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
// ...
inputBox.focusout();
```

Comment: `inputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusout'))` [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dispatchEvent` as a (near) equivalent to jQuery's `trigger`.

```js
document.querySelector('.searchbox-input').dispatchEvent(new Event('focusout'));
```

Comment: Thx mate! instead of reselecting the element i would use the var inputBox. Like that: `inputBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('focusout'));`. Or i have to select new?

Comment: @MaxPattern Are you still using jQuery then?

Comment: no. I dont want use jquery .

Comment: @MaxPattern Then what do you mean by "reselecting the element"? How are you currently selecting it without jQuery?

Comment: i select by querySelector. `const inputBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox');`

Comment: @MaxPattern Then use `inputBox.dispatchEvent(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('searchbox-input').onfocusout = function(){ ... };
```

Comment: Merci mate for good and fast answer :-)

Comment: @MaxPattern 

Comment: @PaulineNemchak Hey Pauline! What means ?